# ssl Mutual authentication certificates

Tags: openssl, x509

I have webservice and client application to access this webservice. I want to use ssl mutual authentication and test it on localhost.

Please guide me how to create 
server certificate and client certificate 
and how to import them on same system for testing

I used following command in openssl to create certificate
openssl> -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
openssl? pkcs12 -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -export -out cert.p12

after creating p12 file i imported into local computer under personal certificates. 
Client application is asking for client certificate. I provided imported certificate issuer name to client application. Now i am getting certificate not found error.

Do i need to create two seperate certificates for server and client. If yes then how to create and import

Client application is c# console application. And webservice is used for uploading xml file.

I have created server and client certificates using following post
https://blog.codeship.com/how-to-set-up-mutual-tls-authentication

In common name for server and client certificates i entered localhost. And installed CA certificate and server certificate on local certificate store and client certificate on user's personal store.

Now I am getting forbidden error.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials.  There are also many different ways to accomplish this, depending on your requirements.  Q: What exactly have you tried, and what specific questions do you have?  Please clarify.

Comment: i used following command in openssl to create certificate

Comment: i used following command in openssl to create certificate
openssl> -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
openssl? pkcs12 -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -export -out cert.p12

after creating p12 file i imported into local computer under personal certificates. 
Client application is asking for client certificate. I provided imported certificate issuer name to client application. Now i am getting certificate not found error. 

Do i need to create two seperate certificates for server and client. If yes then how to create and import

Comment: Please update your original post with this new information.  Also: Q: What is the exact error message?  Q: What is the "client application"?  A standalone C# or Java program?  A Tomcat servlet?  An ASP.Net web app?  Something else?  More importantly - Q: what/where is the client app's [Trust store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates)?